# Debugging not working in VS Studio Code Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I have been working through the [official Django Tutorial in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django) but I have run into an issue. Currently when I ever I set a break-point at the line `now = datetime.now` the debugger seems to fail to reach it.

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from hello import views

urlpatterns = [
path("", views.home, name="home"),
path("hello/<name>", views.hello_there, name="hello_there"),
]
```

My views.py:

```
import re
from django.utils.timezone import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, Django!")

def hello_there(request, name):
    now = datetime.now()
    formatted_now = now.strftime("%A, %d %B, %Y at %X")

    # Filter the name argument to letters only using regular expressions. URL arguments
    # can contain arbitrary text, so we restrict to safe characters only.
    match_object = re.match("[a-zA-Z]+", name)

    if match_object:
        clean_name = match_object.group(0)
    else:
        clean_name = "Friend"

    content = "Hello there, " + clean_name + "! It's " + formatted_now
    return HttpResponse(content)
```

Comment: Have you set `APPEND_SLASH = False` in the settings? If not your url patterns should be ending in a trailing slash so `"hello/<name>"` should be `"hello/<name>/"`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat How do you change that setting? I couldn't find it in the general setting. Regardless I tried adding the trailing slash and I still got the same results.

Comment: Don't change that setting (It is a setting belonging to Django so you can set it in `settings.py`), your issue seems to be something else, I though you were debugging because the page didn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start running the sever before the debugger will go to the break-point. Once you press run wait until it is finished, and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/VSCode. After that the debugger will go to your breakpoint.

Comment: this answer is fine for local testing. the problem is still there for me when invoking the view via pytest (vscode)

Answer (score 1):

As I had the same problem, running VS Code as admin solved it for me.

Comment: Hello, please add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution